# JavaScript - pushing item to an array based off condition

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I am looping through my 2 dimensional array and pushing these items into a new array with object titles. I am attempting to change the name of the object based off of a condition.

Index 1 determines what rank this item is in it's category. I would like to organize my new array and have a condition that reads something like

```
    if(data[0][1] === 1) { 
    ' firstRank': data[i][1] 
    } else if (data[0][1] === 2) {
   'secondRank': data[i][1]
   } else if (data[0][1] === 3) {
   'thirdRank': data[i][1]
   }
```

Here is an example of my code :

```js
const data = [
["Online", 1 ,3.2 ], 
["Appointment", 2 , 2.9],
["Store", 3, 1.8],
] ;

const newData = []

for (let i = 0; i < data[0].length; i++) {
        newData.push({
            'title': data[i][0],
            'rank': data[i][1],
            'percentage': data[i][2],
        })
    }
    
    
    console.log(newData)
```

My expected outcome is for the `newData` array to have a object rank return as `firstRank, secondRank or thirdRank` depending on what the value is equal to in the condition. I've attempted to include this rank within my for loop but I getting syntax errors. Here is what i've attempted:

```
       for (let i = 0; i < data[0].length; i++) {
            newData.push({
         'title': data[i][0],
        if(data[0][1] === 1) { 
        ' firstRank': data[i][1] 
       } else if (data[0][1] === 2) {
      'secondRank': data[i][1]
      } else if (data[0][1] === 3) {
       'thirdRank': data[i][1]
         }
        'percentage': data[i][2],
            })
        }
```

Comment: You'll probably want to construct the object using if statements, and THEN push it onto the array.

Comment: You can use map too like u can keep a counter variable, keep incrementing that on each push and store in the map the mapping from element key to the index at which the element can be found in the array, hope this helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll probably want to construct the object using if statements, and THEN push it onto the array.

```
for (let i = 0; i < data[0].length; i++) {
    // start with what we *know* is going to go into the object
    const myObj = {
        'title': data[i][0],
        'percentage': data[i][2],
    };
    // add additional parts to it based on conditions
    if (data[0][1] === 1) {
        myObj.firstRank = data[i][1];
    } else if (data[0][1] === 2) {
        myObj.secondRank = data[i][1];
    } else if (data[0][1] === 3) {
        myObj.thirdRank = data[i][1];
    }
    // object all ready, add it to the array!
    newData.push(myObj);
}
```

**Note:** The logic looks odd, since `data[0][1]` doesn't change, but this is the logic OP had written.

Answer (score 0):

You can use map and create the object inside the map:

```
const data = [
["Online", 1 ,3.2 ], 
["Appointment", 2 , 2.9],
["Store", 3, 1.8],
] ;

const newData = []

data.map(el => {
  myObj = {
    title: el[0],
    percentage: el[2],
  };
    if(el[1] === 1) {
    myObj['firstRank'] = el[1];
  } else if (el[1] === 2) {
    myObj['secondRank'] =el[1];
  } else if (el[1] === 3) {
    myObj['thirdRank'] = el[1];
  }
  newData.push(myObj);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You know the position of each element: title, rank, and percentage.

Title will be the first element, percentage the last element, and the rank the elements between the first and the last elements.

So, you can do something like this, where the rank will be an array of values, where rank-nth with be array position-nth + 1:

```js
const data = [
  ["Online", 1 ,3.2 ], 
  ["Appointment", 2 , 4, 5, 2.9],
  ["Store", 3, 1.8],
];

const newData = data.map((row) => {
  
  const title = row[0];
  const rank = row.slice(1, row.length-1);
  const percentage = row[row.length - 1];

  return {
    title,
    rank,
    percentage
  }
})

console.log(newData);
```